# WPF Data Grid Example

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I've been experimenting with WPF and just downloaded the toolkit which includes a DataGrid control. Does anyone know where I can find a fully worked through example of binding a database table to the WPF DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/26/wpf-datagrid-working-with-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx) that has some articles on DataGrid binding.